# How to asign same id's to the multiple elements via for loop through every 5 element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to assign id name attribute to the element via for loop, I can actually do that no problem, but i want to accomplished of putting same Id's number in every...let's say 5 element. 
Example:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="3"></div>  
<div id="4"></div>
```

I've tried jquery slice() function, multiple filter selectors and I just can't figure it out. Please point me to the right direction. Every answer so much appreciated .

Comment: It's illegal in HTML to give the same ID to more than one element.

Comment: can it be somehow overwritten

Comment: yes, `id`s can be overwritten using `.attr("id", val)`, but you should not give the same id to multiple elements.

Comment: Your history of questions demonstrate very little research, and very low quality. You might want to look at other questions to learn how to ask properly, and to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Otherwise you're going to end up [being banned from asking questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Comment: yes i understand, but it so useful for pagination in jquery

Comment: **Invalid HTML** 2 ways:  You cannot have _duplicate_ `id`'s, nor can they start with a number.

Comment: @Sparky672 In HTML5 you can start an id with a digit.

Comment: @dystroy, yes true, it depends on OP's `doctype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As absolutely terrible an idea as this is it can be accomplished via jQuery.

```
$('div').each(function (i) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) $(this).attr('id','New Id');
});
```

However, I am assuming you're doing this to style elements, and this is one place newcomers get screwed up is not understanding that ID's are UNIQUE elements, their only real purpose to be honest is to allow you to uniquely select them. To style things similarly on the same page you want to use classes, not ID's. In that case selecting and changing every 5th element to the same CLASS is perfectly valid and a normal thing to do.

```
$('div').each(function (i) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) $(this).addClass('newClass');
});
```

Comment: Now it's clear to me. What a silly question from me. I forgot about classes, main purpose of Id's is to be unique, that is what classes a for. Thanks you so much guys

Comment: The main reason I wanted to do that, was pagination. Let's say.  
Show all divs with id=3 and hide everything else, if you'll click on next page which is number 2, all the div's will bi hidden except the ones that has id=2. Seems like terrible idea, but faster way i suppose

Comment: I'm sorry but where you can accept the answer?

Comment: It should be right below the number beside my answer where the up/down vote thing is.